# How to create a custom hash function in Rust

Tags: rust, hash

How do I create a custom hash function that can be used in HashMap and HashSet? I would like to use Szudzik's pairing function, but all the documentation I have read states that the Hasher uses an arbitrary stream of bytes.

_hash_val is the hash value I would like to be used

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Other_pairing_functions

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Position {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

impl Position {
    // Constructor will pass in x and y
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Self {
        Self { x: x, y: y }
    }

}

impl PartialEq for Position {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.x == other.x && self.y == other.y
    }
}

impl Eq for Position {}

impl Hash for Position {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, _state: &mut H) {
        let x: u64 = self.x.abs() as u64;
        let y: u64 = self.y.abs() as u64;
        let mut _hash_val: u64 = 0;

        /* szudziks function */
        if x >= y {
            _hash_val = x * x + x + y;
        } else {
            _hash_val = x + y * y;
        }
    }
}
```

All the documentation I read states that I need to implement std::hash::Hasher, but [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hasher.html) for that states: `A trait for hashing an arbitrary stream of bytes.`  Is there a way to create a custom hash function that doesn't use an arbitrary stream of bytes?

EDIT:

After reading the first line of the documentation I didn't look any further as I assumed a byte was 8 bits and that's all it could operate on.  But as cdhowie pointed out this is slightly misleading as you can use the write_u64() method.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hasher.html#method.write_u64

Modifying the above Hash implementation using this method:

```
impl Hash for Position {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        assert!(self.x >= 0);
        assert!(self.y >= 0);
    
        let x: u64 = self.x as u64;
        let y: u64 = self.y as u64;
    
        /* szudzik's pairing function */
        let hash_val: u64 = if x >= y {
            x * x + x + y
        } else {
            x + y * y
        };
    
        state.write_u64(hash_val);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create that function, but to implement `Hasher` you have to implement _at least_ `Hasher::write`, which hashes a `&[u8]`. The default implementation of the other `write_*` methods delegate to this one under the hood.

Comment: You might want to combine this approach with [nohash_hasher](https://docs.rs/nohash-hasher/latest/nohash_hasher/) to avoid unnecessary postprocessing of the hash.

Comment: To change the hashing algorithm, you should probably change the hasher, not the `Hash` implementation for the struct.

Answer (score 2):

The hashing used for Rust's hash table collections is a three-step process, managed by three traits.

The `Hash` trait is what elements you want to hash need to implement. All it does is provide bytes to the hasher. You almost have it complete; you just need to write the value to the hasher.

```rust
fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
    let x = self.x.unsigned_abs() as u64;
    let y = self.y.unsigned_abs() as u64;

    /* szudziks function */
    let hash_val = if x >= y { x * x + x + y } else { x + y * y };
    state.write_u64(hash_val);
}
```

I've changed your `abs` to [`unsigned_abs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.unsigned_abs) to avoid overflow. You should also decide how you want to deal with overflow in the multiplication and addition.

This `Hash` impl works for any `Hasher`, so you can use this right away, but since most `Hasher` types don't assume the input is well-distributed (including the default one for `HashMap`/`HashSet`), they will run the bytes through an actual hash function to get the final hash.

If you feel your values are already well-distributed enough for your use case, then you can make a custom hasher that passes the `u64` through unchanged. If you don't ensure the values are well-distributed, you will observe terrible performance for your collections.

```rust
#[derive(Default, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct IdentityHash(u64);

impl Hasher for IdentityHash {
    fn finish(&self) -> u64 {
        self.0
    }
    
    fn write(&mut self, _bytes: &[u8]) {
        panic!("This hasher only takes u64");
    }

    fn write_u64(&mut self, i: u64) {
        self.0 = i;
    }
}
```

There are many ways to do this depending on what you want to happen if the hasher is used for types that aren't a single `u64`, but I've done the simplest possible one as an example.

The last part is `BuildHasher`, which is how the hash table collections reset the hasher between uses. In this case, since `IdentityHash` doesn't have much for state, you can implement this on the same type and have it copy itself.

```rust
impl BuildHasher for IdentityHash {
    type Hasher = Self;

    fn build_hasher(&self) -> Self::Hasher {
        *self
    }
}
```

Now you can create collections with these types.

```rust
fn main() {
    let pos = Position::new(1, 2);
    let mut hasher = IdentityHash::default();
    pos.hash(&mut hasher);
    assert_eq!(hasher.finish(), 5);

    let mut set = std::collections::HashSet::with_hasher(IdentityHash::default());
    set.insert(Position::new(1, 2));
    assert!(set.contains(&Position::new(1, 2)));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2f51f3a7375627518850c95ec6201b38)

Comment: The "identity hasher" is also available as an [external crate](https://docs.rs/nohash-hasher/latest/nohash_hasher/).